# Encoding a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, encode

EDIT : [Schoolwork Assignment]

So, I want to encode, with only 0 and 1, words.

**0 = word not present

1 = word present**

My dictionary correspond to :

```
String[] dictionary = {"Hello", "I", "am", "Lukas", "and", "Jonas", "play", "football"};
```

For example : If I encode these words...

```
String[] listOfWords = {"Hello", "play" "football"};
```

I must have the following array :

```
int[] wordsEncode = {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1};
```

You can see that "Hello" is present, "I" "am" "Lukas" "and" "Jonas" are not present. Finally, "play" and "football" are present.
**We must preserve the order of dictionary and that is my problem in my code.

I don't really know how to fix that problem (using a second for loop ?) ?**
I think **wordEncode[i]** is my **error**, but how to fix that ?

Here is my code :

```
class Dictionary {

    /**
     * Array words Dictionary
     */
    String[] dictionary;
    
    /**
     * Maximum of words MAX_WORDS
     */
    final int MAX_WORDS = 50;
    
    /**
     * Number of words in the dictionary
     */
    int numberWordsDictionary;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    Dictionary() {
        dictionary = new String[MAX_WORDS];
        numberWordsDictionary = 0;
    }

int[] encoder(String[] listOfWords) {
    int[] wordsEncode = new int[numberWordsDictionary];
    
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String word : dictionary) {
        builder.append(word);
    }
    String dictionaryString = builder.toString();     
    
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfWords.length; i++) {
        if(dictionaryString.contains(listOfWords[i])) {
            wordsEncode[i] = 1;
        } else {
            wordsEncode[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return wordsEncode;
}

}
```

Sorry about indentation (not same as my Java IDE) :(
Thanks !

Comment: What do you do if the input is `{"football", "play", "Hello"};`?

Comment: If this is schoolwork assignment, you should say do. That affects what kinds of answers are appropriate.

Comment: You should do as the assignment says, of course. Just so you know, this is not the data structures that one would use in real life. [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two-level nested loops, you should check each element of `dictionary[]` whether it is there in `listOfWords[]` and if yes, update the value at the corresponding index in `wordsEncode[]` to `1`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] dictionary = { "Hello", "I", "am", "Lukas", "and", "Jonas", "play", "football" };
        String[] listOfWords = { "Hello", "play", "football" };
        int[] wordsEncode = new int[dictionary.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
            boolean found = false;
            for (String s : listOfWords) {
                if (s.equals(dictionary[i])) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                wordsEncode[i] = 1;
            }
        }

        // Display the result
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordsEncode));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop your input words. For each input word, see if your list of target words contains that particular word. If so, add a 1 to your results list. If not, add zero.

I use the more convenient Collections, but you could do the same approach with arrays.

```java
List< String > input = List.of( "Hello", "I", "am", "Lukas", "and", "Jonas", "play", "football" ) ;
List< String > targets = List.of( "Hello", "play" "football" ) ;
List< Integers > hits = new ArrayList<>() ;
for( String s : input )
{
    int i = targets.contains( s ) ? 1 : 0 ;
    hits.add( i ) ;
}
```

Comment: I think @OP is in  a class and probably can't use Lists. The question is about adding a 2nd (inner) loop

Comment: @ControlAltDel If this is for schoolwork, the author should say do in the Question. Not my job to read their mind.

Answer (score 0):

What you did here is iterate through dictionary array and added the words to a StringBuilder to check if a certain word you got in the listOfWords array is in the StringBuilder. But there a better solution to this you can just make a nested loop that compares every element of listOfWords array and dictionary array and if it found a match it sets the encode array value at the index of the second loop to 1:

```
int[] encoder(String[] listOfWords) {
    int[] wordsEncode = new int[numberWordsDictionary];

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfWords.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberWordsDictionary; j++) {

            if (listOfWords[i].equals(dictionary[j])) {
                wordsEncode[j] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return wordsEncode;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/* This approach is wrong, the combined string could catch words that are 
  part of the ending of one word and part of the beginning of another but 
  not actually a word in the dictionary. For instance, if you had
  "arch" and "attach" in your dictionary, testing for "chat" would return true
*/
/*
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String word : dictionary) {
        builder.append(word);
    }
    String dictionaryString = builder.toString();     
*/    
    for(int i = 0; i < listOfWords.length; i++) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (int j = 0; j < dictionary.length; j++) {
        if (dictionary[j].equalslistOfWords[i]) {
          found = true;
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        wordsEncode[i] = 1;
      } else {
        wordsEncode[i] = 0;
      }
      // you can also do wordsEncode[i] = found ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return wordsEncode;
}
```